# Die Probability Question + Basics of Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, conditional-probability

A die is rolled twice. What is the probability of observing:

a) a four and a three

P (obtaining a four and a three) or P(obtaining a three and a four)

therefore

P(obtaining a four)* P(obtaining a three) + P(obtaining a three) * P(obtaining a four)

- =(1/6*1/6)+(1/6*1/6)
- =1/18

Would you say, Let A = event 'obtaining a three' and Let B = event 'obtaining a four'?

How else could you solve this probability?

Is it correct to solve this in terms of 'conditional probability:'

that is P(obtaining a three, given you rolled a four) and P(obtaining a four, given you rolled a three) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to solve this question using conditional probability, but since you asked, here is the logic of solving it with that:

P(A and B)=P(A|B)$\cdot$P(B)

P(we got 3 in one die|one die is four)$\cdot$ P(one die is four)=$\frac{1}{6}\cdot \binom{2}{1}\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{18}$

Comment: what about P(we got 4 in one die|one die is three)*P(one die is three) .. why don't we add each? ... wait can we always solve P(A and B) with P(A|B)*P(B) ?

Comment: @confused Equality $P\left(A\text{ and }B\right)=P\left(A\mid B\right)P\left(B\right)$
is *always* valid.

Comment: @confused, the explanation for drhab's comment is that the chance of both event A and B to occur is the same as the chances that B will occur, mutiplied by the chance that (A will occur, knowing B has occured). Beside the fact that that's the definition of conditional probability, you can also see the logic of that definition.

Comment: how do you calculate P(A|B) using the () binomial?

Answer (score 0):

> P(obtaining a four) x P(obtaining a three) + P(obtaining a three) x  P(obtaining a four)
>
> =(1/6*1/6)+(1/6*1/6)

This is correct, because the result of each roll is independent from the other. But $(1/6*1/6)+(1/6*1/6) \neq 2/18$

**Edit**: I have seen, that you have corrected your result.